# How to close a bootstrap dropdown menu with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Alright, I asked a question yesterday that turned out to be completely off base.  I think I'm on more solid ground now but still having an issue.  I have a bootstrap dropdown menu in a button group as follows:

```
<div class="btn-group" id="openItems">
    <button class="btn btn-custom-top dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caption"></span><span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="openItemDropdown">
    </ul>
</div>
```

After moving the mouse out of the menu, I'd like it to close.  I almost have it working but not quite.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('.dropdown-menu').mouseleave(function ()
    {

        $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown('toggle');
    });
});
```

The problem with this is that it toggles all of the dropdowns on the page.  I've tried checking `.hasClass('active')` on `$(this)` but it always returns false.  I suspect this is because `$(this)` is actually the .dropdown-menu node rather than the `.dropdown-toggle` node.  However, traversing the nodes is tricky and doesn't seem to work across all browsers.  There has GOT to be a way to just always close the lists rather than toggling them.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

just add a custom fake class along with dropdown-toggle. for example:

```
<div class="btn-group" id="openItems">
  <button class="btn btn-custom-top myFakeClass dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caption"></span>
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="openItemDropdown"></ul>
</div>
```

then use that as a selector in the script :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.dropdown-menu').mouseleave(function () {
    $(".myFakeClass").dropdown('toggle');
  });
});
```

Comment: So simple!! Why didn't I think of that?  Thank you!

Comment: These people are the legends. Who leave an answer for the generations to learn.

Comment: don't forget to put toggle action into setTimeout, if you call it right from $('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {})

Comment: This worked for me: `$(".dropdown-menu.show").toggle();`

Comment: this worked for me :)  $(".dropdown-menu").removeClass("show");

Answer (score 4):

There's an even easier way to close a Bootstrap dropdown with jQuery:

```
$j(".dropdown.open").toggle();
```

This will close all open dropdowns.

Alternately,

```
$j(".dropdown.open").removeClass("open");
```

This, without any custom code. Of course, it does require you to use the `.dropdown` class, even when it is superfluous, as in the case of a `btn-group`.